# What is the opposite word for Bad luck?

Tags: single-word-requests

B is going to marry Cute Model tomorrow & he is telling to A.

> A: **Lucky boy.**

Here in place of lucky, I want to use opposite word for Bad luck.

Comment: Unlucky, unfortunate, unpropitious, inauspicious, etc. Do you see a pattern here?

Comment: .... Good luck?

Comment: Oh you ***poor*** boy.  Sucks to be you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Fortunate*

> 1 Favored by or involving good luck or fortune; lucky.

([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/fortunate))

Comment: It think OP is asking how B might tease A by pointing out how lucky he (B) is in marrying Cute Girl, while poor A gets nothing.